# Preventing underforecasting of support vector regression in R

Tags: r

I'm currently using the e1071 package in R to forecast product demand using support vector regression via the svm function in the package. While support vector regression yields much higher forecast accuracy for my data compared to other methods (e.g. ARIMA, simple exponential smoothing), my results show that the svm function tends to underforecast. In my particular case, underforecasting is worse and much more expensive than overforecasting. Therefore, I want to implement something in R to tells support vector regression to penalize underforecasting much more than overforecasting.

Unfortunately, I can't really find any possibility to do this. There seems to be nothing on this in the e1071 package. The kernlab package has a support vector function (ksvm) that implements an 'eps-bsvr bound-constraint svm regression' but I can't find any information what is meant by bound-constraint or how to define that bound.

Has anyone seen any examples how to do this in R? I'm only finding very mathematical papers on asymmetric loss functions for support vector regression, and I don't have the skills to translate this into R code, so i'm looking for an already existing solution in R.